# Where is the best way to log response in Restlet

Tags: restlet, jetty-8

I use Restlet with Jetty8.
The Jetty log all incoming calls.
I want to log all response data also, url and body.
Where is the best place to put the log code?

I thought createOutboundRoot is the place but I didn't figured out how to use it and couldn’t find any examples in the web.

Answer (score 0):

I have never tried it but I would start with a Custom filter and override After handle, this appears to be the way Restlet itself does logging internally see the class LogFilter.

Answer (score 0):

implements a log filter like this :

```
public class CustomLogFilter extends Filter {



public CustomLogFilter() {
    super();
}

protected int beforeHandle(Request request, Response response) {
    int returned = super.beforeHandle(request, response);
    // Do specific log if needed
    return returned;
}


protected void afterHandle(Request request, Response response) {
    super.afterHandle(request, response);
    // Do specific log if needed
}
```

}

and use it in your `createInboundRoot` if you have an `Application` object :

```
   public synchronized Restlet createInboundRoot() {
          final Router router = new Router(getContext());
          CustomLogFilter filter = new CustomLogFilter();
          filter.setNext(router);
          return filter;
   }
```